# How to use macro enabled excel file in HP UFT?

Tags: testing, automation, hp-uft

I am using below code

`import Datatable.ExportSheet path, sourcefile, destinationfile`

And I am getting below error

The DataTable.ImportSheet operation failed.   invalid file error

Comment: Please add the whole error message.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting an error message while importing a macro enabled Excel into UFT datatable

Answer is, you can't import a macro enabled Excel (xlsm) file into UFT datatable. The reason being, Datatable.ImportSheet accepts only .xls or .xlsx file extensions.

Workaround is, save the xlsm file as *Excel 97-2003 Workbook (xls)* format using Save As function from Excel. Or save the xlsm file as *Excel Workbook (xlsx)* format.

Comment: With same problem, I included saving excel as new excel with results of macro with .xlsx extention in the macro, and imported the result file to UFT